# Prove Matrix is Primitive

Tags: matrices, induction

I have been asked the following question

> A stochastic matrix is called primitive if there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $A^k$ is a positive matrix
>
> Prove that
>
> $$S = \begin{pmatrix}
>  1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
> 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 \\
> 0&1/3&1/3&1/3& \\
>  1/3 &0 &1/3&1/3
> \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> is a primitive stochastic matrix

I have attempted to prove this using induction however I am not certain if the proof is correct and would appreciate any advice for answering this question

ATTEMPTED PROOF:

Proof by Induction

Case k = 1 
 $$S^1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 \\
0&1/3&1/3&1/3& \\
 1/3 &0 &1/3&1/3
\end{pmatrix} 
$$ Since each element is positive it holds for k = 1

Case k = 2
 $$S^2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1/3 & 2/9 & 2/9 & 2/9 \\
2/9 & 1/3 & 2/9 & 2/9 \\
2/9 &2/9 &1/3&2/9\\
2/9 & 2/9 &2/9 &1/3 
\end{pmatrix} >0
$$

therefore assumption holds for k = 2

Assume true for k = n such that  $S^n > 0$

Case k = n+1

$S^{(n+1)} = S^nS^1$

Since $S^{n} > 0$ and $S^1 >0$ then it follows that $S^{n+1} >0 $

Therefore S is a positive matrix for any integer k

Comment: $S^1$ has some zeros. You could do two inductions: One that starts as $S^2$ and multiplies by $S^2$ each time, and the other that starts at $S^3$ and multiplies by $S^2$ each time. The first would cover the even powers and the second the odd powers larger than $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sufficient condition to prove a matrix is primitive is for the matrix to be non-negative, irreducible and with positive elements in the main diagonal.
It's clear $S$ is non-negative and there is positive elements in the main diagonal. A matrix is irreducible if it is not similar via permutation to a block upper triangular matrix ( that has more than one block of positive size ).
To show that $S$ is irreducible, create an adjacency matrix by replacing the positive values in $S$ with $1$ and show that it is strongly-connected. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component

Answer (score 2):

You only have to prove it for one such $k$. In any case, once you have found a matrix $A^k >0$, all $A^n >0$ for any $n > k$.